# Поделитесь опытом , какие библиотеки для Чартов ( графиков ) юзаете ?

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-программирование, диаграммы

Доброе утро ! Поставили задачу , требующую реализацию графиков. Подскажите по своему опыту самую сочную и крутую библиотеку , пожст

Comment: [Google Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/). Полный список чартов: [Google Charts](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery)

Comment: остановился на Highcharts, пользовал flot и еще что-то, chartjs мб. chartist неплохи вроде, сам не юзал.

Comment: highcharts хорош, поддерживаю.

Comment: http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/?q=

Comment: https://gionkunz.github.io/chartist-js/examples.html

Answer (score 1):

Из самых распространенных:

- [Chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/) - из плюсов, требуется подключить всего 1 js файл чтобы сразу всё работало. Графиков не так много, но для большинства целей хватает
- [Highcharts](https://www.highcharts.com/products/highcharts/) - большое количество разнообразных графиков и очень гибкие настройки
- [ECharts](https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-examples/public/index.html) - сумрачное творение китайского гения с огромным количеством всевозможных графиков

А в целом можно изучить пару обзоров библиотек [тут](https://www.sitepoint.com/15-best-javascript-charting-libraries/) или [тут](https://hackernoon.com/9-best-javascript-charting-libraries-46e7f4dc34e6)

Comment: А подскажите , пожст 
В Chart.js можно свою инфу в это всплывающее черное поле ввести ? 
В type = 'bar'

Comment: @IvanZagorskiy о каком конкретном поле идёт речь, можно пример?

Comment: http://ibb.co/dbLuFx
По ссылке выложил

Comment: Если я правильно понял, вас интересует нечто вроде https://prnt.sc/ikvzkt  Это свойство datasets.label  код:     
`            const barChartData = {
                labels: dataSets.labels,
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'Тут может быть что угодно',
                    backgroundColor: getRandomColor(),
                    data: dataSets.sets
                }]
            }; `  и затем его в Chart.data. Нашел пример https://jsfiddle.net/rch183nz/1/

Comment: ну тогда и заголовок изменится у всего блока чарта

Comment: @IvanZagorskiy это настраивается, по умолчанию заголовок цепляется от названия датасета, а label даёт возможность задать расшифровку значения. Пример: https://jsfiddle.net/az4pbu6a/